# Delphi DBGrid disable clicking on another row when editing

Tags: delphi, dbgrid

I have a dbgrid displaying data from a Ttable and my problem is that when
editing a row in the grid the focus is on the row that I want to edit but I can
still click on another row and edit it. How do I disable clicking on another row 
or keep focus on the same row?

Second question is (still on the dbgrid) when I edit a column and double click on that column,
the focus moves to the end of the text line therefor not showing the original text but only showing maybe the last character and spaces.

Please help...

Comment: Why would you want to? Just see clicking on another row as a Save or a Cancel (pick one and be consistent across all grids in your app).

Comment: Btw, you will probably get better answers when you ask one question per, well..., question.

Comment: Point taken, lets start with the first question, how do I disable editing another row that wasn't initially selected?

Comment: why do you want to limit your user to click wherever she wants?

Comment: Because when the table is on edit mode, if the user goes and click on another row, she is able to edit that particular row and this is unacceptable, one should only edit the row she's on otherwise cancel the edit and select another row then click on edit button to edit the selected row. Hope you get what I'm on about. NB: I do have an ok button to post the changes.

Comment: Set TDataSource.AutoEdit to false

Comment: Sir Rufo, at which point do I set auto edit to false? Because setting auto edit to false still allows the user to go on and click on other rows and therefore moving the focus from the row to be edited BUT cant edit other rows even the one to be edited. So with setting the thing to false, now I just cant edit at all.

Comment: "otherwise cancel the edit and select another row then click on edit button to edit the selected row" - did you have a edit button or not?

Comment: I do have an edit button and an ok (post) button.

Comment: It is not clear what you really want, reading your question and comments. Q: No row change at all while in edit mode, C: Row change should cancel actual edit and edit should start with a button

Comment: If you don't want the user to edit any other record, don't use a grid to edit it, use a form with a single record view. :)

Answer (score 0):

After a while of playing around with this, I've discovered that there's no easy way
to disable the user from moving from the highlighted row (row to edit) when clicking another row.
The best way is to cancel when he clicks on another row, I'm using a TTable and TQuery, so 
on the BeforePost event, just do a cancel on your table or query. But you also need to do the
same on the AfterScroll even, just in case.

Thanks for all your help.